# Cucumber Cluecumber Reports - POM : Pass command line inPOM file instead typing in Terminal

Tags: maven, command-line, pom.xml, maven-plugin, cucumber-jvm

Hi community: I'm running the cucumber execution and after this process I have to generate the Cluecumber Reports via command line in Terminal with the command `mvn cluecumber-report:reporting`

The think that I look for is add this command in POM file plugin for generating this reports after execution instead of typing that command manually.

This is the plugin configurated in my pom:

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>com.trivago.rta</groupId>
            <artifactId>cluecumber-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>reporting</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <sourceJsonReportDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cluecumber-report</sourceJsonReportDirectory>
                <generatedHtmlReportDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cluecumber-report/cluecumber_report_${maven.build.timestamp}</generatedHtmlReportDirectory>
                <customCss>custom/cluecumber.css</customCss>
                <skip>false</skip>  <!-- This property is used to skip the report generation. The default value is false -->
                <failScenariosOnPendingOrUndefinedSteps>false</failScenariosOnPendingOrUndefinedSteps>
                <expandBeforeAfterHooks>false</expandBeforeAfterHooks>
                <expandStepHooks>false</expandStepHooks>
                <expandDocStrings>false</expandDocStrings>
                <customPageTitle>This is the Page title</customPageTitle> <!-- This is for changing the report title -->
                <!-- Here below it's possible  to change the colors -->
                <customStatusColorPassed>#017FAF</customStatusColorPassed>
                <customStatusColorFailed>#C94A38</customStatusColorFailed>
                <customStatusColorSkipped>#F48F00</customStatusColorSkipped>
                <customParameters>
                        <Custom_Parameter>This is the First Navigation Test</Custom_Parameter>
                        <Custom_URL>http://www.google.com</Custom_URL>
                        <_Text>The goal here is going to Google.com and search for an specific idea and continue the flow</_Text>
                </customParameters>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Is there a way to reach that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not using `mvn clean verify` which includes the `post-integration-test` phase and should execute the reporting goal?

Comment: Could you please explain how to do that?

Comment: Have you checked to execute the given command `mvn clean verify`?

Comment: When I execute mvn clean verify it delete old reports

Comment: Yes of course if you do `mvn clean` cause that will delete `target` directory...not astonishing...? So where is the problem?

Comment: What I want is add the command in POM not typing in console/terminal

Comment: Depending on where you have configuration your reporting part it should work via `mvn verify`...So you wrote in the beginning: "command line in Terminal with the command mvn cluecumber-report:reporting" and now you write: not typing in console/terminal? I'm confused I don't understand what you like to achieve and where?

Comment: that I look for is add this command in POM file plugin instead of typing again and again after any execution

Comment: Hm. `mvn verify`? What should be typed instead? Apart from that do you use and IDE? Using a CI solution?

Comment: mvn cluecumber-report:reporting